# Pandas Dataframe not update column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

This is `print(df['Title'])` result.

I am performing regex to replace unnecessary characters

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
    return re.sub(r']!@-#$%^&*(){};:,./<>?\|`~=_+',' ',text)

df1 = pd.read_csv(file2)
print(df1["Title"])
df1['Title'] = df1['Title'].apply(remove_punctuations)
print(df1["Title"])
```

What I am doing wrong. Please anyone point this out.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be enclosing the special characters inside a character class, which is denoted by `[...]` square brackets:

```py
def remove_punctuations(text):
    return re.sub(r'\s*[\[\]!@#$%^&*(){};:,./<>?\|`~=_+-]\s*', ' ', text).strip()
```

Note that the replacement logic used replaces standalone special characters with a single space.  For the edge cases where special characters might start or end the input, we use `strip()`.

Comment: Can you tell if I want to replace square brackets too. How can I do that ?

Comment: My answer should already be replacing square brackets.  Look closely.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex expression is looking for an exact chain of `"]!@-#$%^&*(){};:,./<>?\|` punctuations before substituting with a blank `" "`.

Replace your function with:

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',text)
```

where it would look for any instance  of punctuations or white space.